# How to determine how many times an ext3 file system has been mounted

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, ext3

A few months ago I created an ext3 file system on one of my partitions. I received the following message:

`"mkfs.ext3 /dev/sddx; system will be checked every 20 mounts or 180 days; use
tune2fs -c or -i to override".`

How can I determine how many times this file system has been mounted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tune2fs -l /dev/sddX` will give the info you need, in particular the "Mount count" and "Last mount time"